# Code with Opencv4 compiles but not links- not finding Mat and imshow

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, g++, undefined-reference

I am trying to create executable of following code taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-displaying-an-image-in-opencv-using-c/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// Driver code
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read the image file as   // imread("default.jpg");
    Mat image = imread("barchart.png",  IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Error Handling
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image File Not Found" << endl;

        // wait for any key press
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    // Show Image inside a window with the name provided
    imshow("Window Name", image);

    // Wait for any keystroke
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles all right with command `g++ showimage.cpp -c -I /usr/include/opencv4` and creates an `showimage.o` file

However, following command to link it gives error:

```
g++ showimage.o -l:libopencv_imgcodecs.a

...
... (lot of output)
/usr/bin/ld: showimage.o: in function `main':
showimage.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::empty() const'
/usr/bin/ld: showimage.cpp:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: showimage.cpp:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: showimage.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/bin/ld: showimage.cpp:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried following option:

```
g++ showimage.o -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
g++ showimage.o -L libopencv
g++ showimage.o -L opencv
```

But none is not working.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: You're not linking against the opencv library. So your linker can't find the functions from the library.

Comment: `libopencv_imgcodecs.a` is not enough.

Comment: I also tried `-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` but it does not work. That has imagecodecs files.

Comment: That just adds the folder which should already be one of the folders the linker already looks.

Comment: Opencv has eirher a big list of libs, one for each module, or single _world library. Try to link opencv_core opencv_highgui etc.

Comment: There are many in opencv directory. Should I include all? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Linking only the ones you need. But when starting out link all the ones isn't even a bad option.

Comment: Try core (Mat) and highgui (imshow) and maybe imgcodecs and videoio, not sure